# Aligning AppBar items - Material UI and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I'm trying to align the `CloseIcon` as `flex-end` so that it floats right but can't find where to apply that style.

```
import React from 'react';
    import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
    import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
    import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
    import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
    import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
    import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
    import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
    import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
    import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
    import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
    import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
    import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
    import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
    import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
    import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
 



const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: 36,
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
  },
  drawerOpen: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  drawerClose: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing(9) + 1,
    },
  },
  toolbar: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

export default function MiniDrawer() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [mobileMoreAnchorEl, setMobileMoreAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl);

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
//   const { performingAction, user, userData, roles } = this.props;

  const handleMobileMenuClose = () => {
    setMobileMoreAnchorEl(null);
  };
  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
      
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open,
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, {
              [classes.hide]: open,
            })}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap style={{ letterSpacing: '.5rem'}}>title
          </Typography>
          <IconButton color="inherit">

            <CloseIcon />
          </IconButton>    
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
```

This code sandbox shows it smashed up against the label on the left side.

[image: Edit Switch text change]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple one-liner for the button:

```css
margin-left: auto;
```

Or in JSS:

```js
marginLeft: "auto"
```

Comment: Nice one! Could add inline like this `<IconButton style={{marginLeft: "auto"}} color="inherit">`

Comment: Thank you. I can't give you the points until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to put a div between logo and close icon and set style to grow

```
<div style={{flexGrow: "1"}}></div>
```